# A hash Map in which on of the value object's fields is the key?

Tags: java, hashmap

I was wondering if there was an class like HashMap in which the key is an identifying field in the object.

If there is not, I was thinking about having the class I use as the value implement Map.Entry.  Does this seem like a reasonable approach or does that seem dangerous?  (I'll make my key field immutable.)

Comment: How does your object look like?

Comment: Why would you need a special map for this? Create a class `V`, give it a member field `K`, and create a `Map<K,V>`.

Comment: On second thought, my concept of making the value implement Map.Entry is not viable because Map.Entry has a public method setValue().  Since I can't set "this" to be another value, it can't really be done.

Answer (score 4):

> I was thinking about having the class I use as the value implement Map.Entry. Does this seem like a reasonable approach or does that seem dangerous?

Dangerous or not, it is bad design since it violates the *single-responsibility principle*.  A class should not be responsible for doing its own stuff, and also being a Map.Entry.  What happens when you now want to use it in another library?  Do you have to implement another interface?

While it's unclear to me what you hope to gain by implementing `Map.Entry` (are you trying to extend `AbstractMap`?), I can tell you this smells bad to me and I have never seen it done in practice.

What's the actual issue here?  What's wrong with using a `HashMap`?

```
Map<String, MyClass> map = new HashMap<String, MyClass>();
MyClass myObj = new MyClass("myId");

//...
map.put(myObj.getIdentifier(), myObj);

MyClass retrievedObj = map.get("myId");
```

Comment: I think your basic point is correct.  I was just trying to make things less verbose, but in the process I was probably being a little to fancy.

Answer (score 3):

When you add objects (or classes) to the hashmap, you select the key feild being sent to the map. Just make a getKey() method inside your class which will return your desired key.

Then use it when inserting an object to the map

For example, if you have a Person Class with ID (String) as key. Make this function:

```
public String getKey()
{
   return this.Id; //Or use the getter method
}
```

And use it when inserting the Person object to the map:

```
Person1.getKey();
```

Comment: I like to name methods after what they do/are, not what they're going to be used for. What are you going to do when you want to create an array of `Person` objects, are you going to add a `getIndex()` method to `Person`? I'd recommend not naming your method `getKey()` because you'll almost definitely use it in a context that is for something other than a key into your map. If your `getKey()` is going to return the Id of the person then there's no need for `getKey()`, just use `getId()`.

Answer (score 0):

You could always use HashMap and add the field as the key (if you were going to make it immutable anyway, i don't see any problem with that).

Answer (score 0):

It's the `HashMap` itself. Just make sure that the "identifying field" in the object properly implements the `equals()` and `hashCode()` methods.

e.g. If your class is:

```
public class YourObject {
    private String identifyingField;
```

Then:

```
Map<String, YourObject> yourMap = new HashMap<String, YourObject>();
```